# programmatically convert a string of datastore key for a new app ID? (Master/slave -> HRD migration)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I've inherited an app which has entity keys stored as strings rather than actual Keys so of course they are not updated by the automatic tool for migration to the HRD datastore.

Can I programmatically (and if so, how) convert the keys stored as strings into strings which represent the new keys for the new app ID? (setting aside the fact that they should not be stored as strings in the first place).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you are using `ndb`:

```
new_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=string_value_of_key)
```

and to change the app ID, you can access the protected attribute `__app` via the public attribute `_Key__app`

```
new_key._Key__app = 'new-app-id'
```

### If you are using `db`:

```
old_key = db.Key(encoded=string_value_of_key)
```

Then to convert the key to one with your new app ID, you can use

```
new_key = db.Key.from_path(*old_key.to_path(), 
                           _app='new-app-id',
                           parent=old_key.parent(), 
                           namespace=old_key.namespace())
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way thankfully, using the Key Class. The below only works for keys of entities that don't have parents but I believe this method could be generalized for entities with parents using the parent() method of the Key class.

You run this code in your NEW app to get the new key string:

```
old_key = db.Key('old_key_string_in_here')
new_key = db.Key.from_path(old_key.kind(), old_key.id())
new_key_string = str(new_key)
```